# Drupal 9 adding a custom theme not showing at Appearance

Tags: drupal, yaml, themes, drupal-9

So I am trying to add a custom theme to a new Drupal 9 site, but the theme is not showing in my Appearance tab at all. I followed few fixes and tutorials but with no luck at all. Not sure what to do at this point. I am very very new to Drupal and very very lost.

This is what i did:

[image]

Aside of that there is no error messages or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please swap the dashes with underscores (`test_theme`) in your theme directory and info YAML file.

As per the documentation on [Name your theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file#s-name-your-module), stating:

> There are some important rules to follow when selecting a machine name:
>
> - It must start with a letter.
> - **It must contain only lower-case letters, numbers and underscores.**
> - It must not contain any spaces.
> - It must not be longer than 50 characters.
> - It must be unique. Your theme should not have the same short name as any other module, theme, theme engine, or installation profile you will be using on the site.
> - It should not be any of the reserved terms (folders in the Drupal distribution): src, lib, vendor, assets, css, files, images, js, misc, templates, includes, fixtures, drupal.

Comment: aaah i missed this point!!! Thank youuu